# How to handle a UIScreenEdgeGestureRecognizer with a map view covering the whole view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have iOS program over here, with a map view covering the whole container view. I want the map view to handle the `UIScreenEdgeRecognizer`, since it is covering the whole container view. *I think* it would be better to let the `gestureRecognizers` array to reference the recognizer. But the pan gesture of the map view is interrupting the screen edge recogniser. I tried `gestureRecognizer:shouldFailRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer` and all that, but it still doesn't work. But solution would you people recommend? Could I let the `gestureRecognizers` array of the container view reference the screen edge recogniser?

Comment: You need to show us your code or your XIB layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I did was to add a view with a 10pt width and clear color background over the edge I needed the gesture recognizer and I added the gesture recognizer to this view.

In the picture, the white rectangle on the right is the view which will have the gesture recognizer. You should change the background color to clear color.

[image: A way to add a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer on a map view]

The view outlet:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *rightEdgeGestureView;
```

Add the gesture recognizer to the view on the screen right edge:

```
- (void)setupGestureRecognizer {

      UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureHandler:)];
      gestureRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeRight;
      [_rightEdgeGestureView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
 }
```

Comment: Nice idea. Thank you so much.